# Confusion in study of derivative of a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

I have some confusion about the study of the derivatives in $x=0$ of this piecewise function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right), \ \text{if} \ x>0 \\ 0, \ \text{if} \ x \leq 0\end{cases}$$
Here's my doubts:

1. $f$ is $0$ for $x=0$, so why can't I just say that $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$ and so $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ for $x=0$ because the derivatives $f^{(n)}(0)$ are $0$ are $0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ since I'm doing every time the derivative of the function $0$? I suspect that I'm doing wrong because of the order, that is $f'(0)$ means "first evaluate the derivative, then put $x=0$" and not vice versa.
2. I know that in general, when a function is piecewise defined, in the study of continuity and differentiability I have to check every point where the definition of the function changes, but I don't really know from the theory why I have to do this; why is like this? Usually, the theorems of differnetial calculus say that if we know that a function is differentiable in a set we can just use the differentiation rules, and since the two functions in the piecewise definition of $f$ are differentiable in both $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0]$ can't I just say that, for the theorems of differentiation rules, $\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ is differentiable for all $x>0$ and $0$ is differentiable for all $x \leq 0$ and evaluate the derivatives with the classical rules? Is there a reason that when a function changes definition the theorems cannot be applied anymore? What makes us say that we don't know the behaviour of $f$ in the points of change of definition, and so we must proceed with the definition in those points?

Comment: Continuity and differentiability are "neighbourhood" properties. They depend not just on the value of $f(0)$ but also values of $f(x)$ in neighbourhoods of $0$. Since the function definition changes at $0$ we can no longer be sure that the right hand derivative of $f$ at $0$ is zero.

Comment: Put another way:  differentiation is defined by considering the limit $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$ as $h$ approaches zero from either side, that is through negative values and through positive values.  For negative values, you rightly argue we are just differentiating the constant function $f(x) = 0$, but for positive values you need to think about how $\exp-1/(x+h)^2)$ and its higher derivatives behave in (0,\infty) as $h \to 0$ with $h > 0$.